# cakephp: no save, no validate errors, no callbacks, empty sql log

Tags: cakephp, model, save

In my controller i have this add function:

```
public function add(){
    $this->layout = false;
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Paciente->create(); 
        $this->Paciente->set($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Paciente->validates()) {
            if($this->Paciente->save()){
                 $this->set('status', '200');
            } else {
             //   debug($this->Paciente->validationErrors);
             //   ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
         //       var_dump($this->Paciente);

                $this->set('status', '101');
            //    $log = $this->Paciente->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
          //      debug($log);

               // die;
             }
        } else {
            // didn't validate logic
   //         $errors = $this->Paciente->validationErrors;
     //       debug($errors);
            $this->set('status', '100');

        }

    } else

     $this->set('status', '404');

}
```

I'm sending the post info and the status is always 101. As you can see I have tried a lot to find out where is the error, but no luck.

Also I don't have any callback in my Model (beforeSave, afterSave...)...

Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: you disabled layout. is your need ? just try to remove that line and try.

Comment: is your debug level on 2? what does the logging say?

Comment: I recommend you simply debug the save method and determine where it returns false - based on that it should be clearer how your model validates but doesn't save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way i was sending the post info:

I was setting the variables as data['Model']['var'] and the correct way is data[Model][var]

Thanks @mark, @AD7six, @liyakat and @Alex for your help in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
if ($this->Paciente->validates()) {
        if($this->Paciente->save()) {
}
```

is wrong.
You are validating twice.

Please - as documented - either use false (`save(null, false)`) to not invalidate twice or simply remove the validates() part here.
You can directly do:

```
if ($this->Paciente->save($this->request->data)) {}
```

This itself is unlikely causing your issue, though.
Or do you have some custom validation rules that on second (and faulty) trigger will make a field invalidate?
You can confirm that by checking `$this->Paciente->validationErrors` afterwards. It should be empty. If it does not save (and it's for sure no callback), and if it does not throw exceptions due to SQL errors then it most likely are your validation rules.

Comment: While calling validate your before save is unnecessary - removing the call to validates will not change how calling save acts - it will not address the problem in the question. -1

Comment: it might, if there are callbacks in play. which - it seems from the question - it is not the case, though. So no, it is indeed unlikely that this is the issue itself, but its still something that needs to be pointed out - and complicates/bloats the code itself. There could be some callback in the AppModel maybe? At some point something must return false prior to saving to run into the 101 case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine. When you set your array values like above it would likely break in php5.3 >